# Is there a fork of SocketRocket that is more stable or actively developed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, socketrocket

I've been using SocketRocket for a few projects and have noticed that SocketRocket has quite a few unresolved issues and is buggy. I have personally patched a few crashes that I have experienced.

Square does not appear to have been maintaining SocketRocket over the past year. Is there another fork of their repo that is considered to be more stable/authoritative?

I would even be willing to consider an alternate library, maybe even one that's written in C/C++ if it can play nice with ObjC coding patterns.